# Upload *.odt file to Google Docs: images don't load

Tags: image, upload, google-docs, openoffice.org

I just tried to upload an *.odt file to my Google Docs. So far, everything worked fine, except that the images do not load. Has anybody got this to work? Or is it a missing feature?

I'm on OSX Lion, and I use the latest version of Google Chrome and NeoOffice (an OSX-version of OpenOffice.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it has been a temporary problem, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you include the pictures as links/reference ? (in the dialog box to insert a picture)

You can check image src attribute value. Unzip the odt file, then open/edit content.xml and search for image tag. If the picture is included (no link/reference), you should find it in Pictures folder, next to content.xml

Comment: Thanks, the images are in the Pictures folder. Here's the document in question, maybe you can check it out? [ODT doc](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/89967110/document_to_convert.odt) Thank you!

Comment: I can't check, company proxy and no ooffice... If the picture is inside, you didn't include it as a "reference", it's probably a Google Doc non support / bug

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check on that later.